# Строки в PHP

Tags: php, строки

В скрипте появляется сообщение:

> "Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 1"

Вот кусочек кода:

```
<?php
$a=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
switch ($a[1]) //проблемная строка
...
```

Подскажите, в чем дело и как это исправить?

Comment: Ребят. @Siter & @Asen. Вы не выспались чтоли? В $a лежит строка например "/news/1". @Antiless, просто сделай switch($a). У строки нет индексов.

Comment: Сам, что ли, не выспался? =) В $a может лежать и '/'.

Comment: Никто не утверждал обратного

Comment: в принципе может быть все что угодно, если пользователь решит поэкспериментировать с запросами

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` - строка

Соответственно `$a[1]` - 2-й символ строки

Соответственно, когда строка не содержит такого символа, падает `notice`.

Comment: кстати, это первый символ, но не суть - я не понял почему предупреждение появляется

Comment: Предупреждение появляется, если строка пустая. Про isset написали верно.

Answer (score 1):

А кто проверку на существование индекса будет делать?

```
if(isset($a[1])){
    //switch(...)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну раз еще не выделен правильный ответ, я тоже поэксперементирую паранормальными силами

Как было сказано выше, **$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']**, действительно строка, и в **$a[1]** будет второй символ **REQUEST_URI**, т.е. как показывает практика, второй символ IP адреса

Рискну предположить:

1) Вы хотите работать с несколькими IP адресами, и к каждому делать свое действие, тогда имеет смысл код:

```
$a = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
switch($a)
{action}
```

2) Вы даёте переменной $a значения массива $_SERVER (это если истинна только вторая часть кода), тогда:

```
$a = $_SERVER;
switch($a[1])
{action}
```

P.S. var_dump($_SERVER) дабы уточнить индекс REQUEST_URI